# Java + Writing XML

Tags: java, xml

I data in the below format (List of HashMap's)

```
{TeamName=India, Name=Sachin, Score=170}
{TeamName=India, Name=Sehwag, Score=120}
{TeamName=Sri-Lanka, Name=Sangakara, Score=20}
{TeamName=Sri-Lanka, Name=Murali, Score=20}
{TeamName=Sri-Lanka, Name=Jayasurya, Score=70}
```

I have to generate the following XML structure:

```
<node id="1" label="India" >
        <node id="1.1" label="Sachin" Score="170" />
        <node id="1.2" label="Sehwag" Score="120" />
</node>
<node id="2" label="Sri-Lanka">
      <node id="2.1" label="Sangakara" Score="20" />
      <node id="2.2" label="Murali" Score="20" />
      <node id="2.3" label="Jayasurya" Score="70" />
</node>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you know how to iterate a Map, and write basic Java loops, so will point you to an article I wrote on XML output: http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=xml.builder

Comment: @kdgregory Your link is excellent, worth reading and possibly discussing. I suggest you make a full answer out of it! I need to vote for it, and remember and bookmark it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a nested structure of `HashMap`s to collect the teams. The outer map has the name of the team as key and another map as value. The inner map maps players to scores.
2. Iterate over this structure and emit the XML with the XML writer of your choice. Try [JDom](http://www.jdom.org/) or [StAX](http://stax.codehaus.org/Home).